# Google Maps "directions" map maker function fails to utilize direct route due to road closure entry

Tags: google-maps

Recently, when planning a trip to Yellowstone Natl Park, the Grand Loop Rd between Tower Junction and Canyon Village will not be included in any trip due to Google Maps inclusion of a road closure. Even one planning a route directly from Tower Junction to Canyon Village will be directed around the entire rest of the loop excluding the most direct route. Previously (approx. 2 yrs ago), this route was available, as I had planned an extensive trip including this route, and the map included this stretch of road. I am wondering if it has something to do with the "road closure" notice, or labels saying "(Closed winters)", but other roads in the region (i.e., Norris Canyon Rd) are so labeled but allow planning to use these routes. How does one plan a future trip without consideration of present road closures?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Departure options" dropdown to select "Depart at" instead of "Leave now":
[image]

Then you can enter time and date of your departure that will be used to calculate your route:
[image]

Comment: OK, I tried to enter WorldMark West Yellowstone as the starting point and Lake Yellowstone Hotel as destination, but the direct route plan does not include Mammoth Hot springs, Tower Junction and Canyon Village via the Grand Loop. Drag and drop does not allow changing the route. The "Leave now" option no longer appears once you insert an additional destination to include the Tower Junction loop. How do I maintain the "Leave now" option and still add destinations?

Comment: You are right, multiple destinations are not available with "Depart at" feature, what you need to do is get directions from first to second point, then from second to third point, and so on